# Проблема с SQL запросом

Tags: mysql

Имеется такой вот SQL запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `board` WHERE `status`='1' AND `cat`='100500' OR `srochno`='1' OR `vydelit`='1' OR `top`='1'
```

Проблема в том, что выводятся данные из бд, даже если значания srochno, vydelit и top равны нулю.

Как поправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы скорее всего запутались в OR и AND:

Может вы так хотели:

```
SELECT * FROM `board` WHERE `status`='1' AND `cat`='100500' OR (`srochno`='1' AND `vydelit`='1' AND `top`='1')
```

или так:

```
SELECT * FROM `board` WHERE `status`='1' AND `cat`='100500' AND `srochno`='1' AND `vydelit`='1' AND `top`='1'
```

или так (**скорее всего так**):

```
SELECT * FROM `board` WHERE `status`='1' AND `cat`='100500' AND (`srochno`='1' OR `vydelit`='1' OR `top`='1')
```

Comment: Нужно вывести значания из бд где srochno равно единице или vydelit равно единице или top равно единице.

Comment: 3-ий вариант, который я предложил, не забудьте скобки :)

Comment: Третий вариант то что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: пожалуйста )